# How can I add noise to my black and white bitmap image?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I have a black and white image that I need to store location of the back pixels and then add some noise by turning for example  half of them to white randomly.
can anyone tell me how can i store the location of ONLY black pixels and randomly turn half of them to white color?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Which part you have problem? be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `List<Point>` to store your black pixels. Then just iterate through it and change them randomly:

```
List<Point> blackPixels = new List<Point>();
```

Now in your loop above:

```
else if (color.ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb())
{
        blackColor++;
        blackPixels.Add(new Point(x,y));
}
```

And when you want to add noise just do something like:

```
Random r = new Random();

foreach(Point p in blackPixels) 
{
    if(r.NextDouble() < 0.5) 
    {
        bmp.SetPixel(p.X,p.Y,Color.White);
    }
}
```

This will *statistically* set about half your black pixels to white, but it may be more or less. If you truly want *exactly* half, then you can just randomly pick a set n/2 random numbers from 0 to n without repeats and toggle the pixels at those indexes in `blackPixels`. Or you could even shuffle your list of `blackPixels` and then change the first n/2 of them.

Note, however, that the performance of `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` isn't great. If your image is large, be sure to check out [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for better performance.

Comment: Matt Burland, i just tried your code it actually doesn't add any noise it just print the image again...

Comment: could you please tell me how i can print my new bmp image?

Comment: @user3266873: My mistake, should be `NextDouble` not `Next`. `Next` returns an int so it's very unlikely to be less than < 0.5!